# Unexpected end of input despite passing JSLInt

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's a bit silly, I really can't find the syntax error here, yet the chrome debugger tells me he hits an "unexpected end of input" in line two. Does anyone have an idea?

```
$("head meta").each(function () {
    var content = JSON.parse(this.content);
    if (content.hasOwnProperty("bitpenny")) {
        checkWhiteList(window.location.hostname, function (isIn, entry) {
            if (!isIn) {
                checkBlackList(window.location.hostname, function (isIn) {
                    if (!isIn) {
                        askUser(content, window.location.hostname);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems like error raises in `JSON.parse` function. Are you sure your JSON is valid? Can you provide `this.content` content?

Comment: Which elements in `head meta` are you expecting to be JSON? If even one of them isn't, you'll get that error. A [try..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) might be useful here.

Comment: You are right. I considered this possibility. this.content was an empty string "". I just now realized that this isn't valid json either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think you can parse any string as JSON ?

This fails

```
var content = JSON.parse('text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

as it should, and `this.content` will return something similar, as it's the text from the content meta tag, and you can't parse that as JSON

Comment: You are right. I had checked that possibility by changing the code to JSON.parse(""). I just now realized that this wasn't valid Json either.